# PHP = Dropdown From DB and execute the price when I select one in the dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to show the price inside the textbox when I choose one item inside the dropdown.

Here's my code connected to the database.

```
<?php
// my connection here
?>
<?php
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM products");
    echo '<select>';
        while($obj = $query->fetch_object()){
            echo '
                <option value"'.$obj->product_name.'">'.$obj->product_name.'</option>
        ';
    }
echo '</select>';
// if product1 is selected, the price is 100 and show in the textbox
//
?>
```

Comment: Product Name and Price is in same table ??

Comment: yes sir. its the same table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where did you store the price for the products? If they are also inside the Database then add them as a attribute to the option-tag. Wehen selecting the option inside the selection simply read the attribute via jquery and set the value of the text box.

```
<?php
// your connection here :)
?>
<?php
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM products");
    echo '<select onChange="$(#output).val($(this).find('option:selected').attr('price'))">';
        while($obj = $query->fetch_object()){
            echo '
                <option value"'.$obj->product_name.'" price="'.$obj->price.'">'.$obj->product_name.'</option>
        ';
    }
    echo '</select>';
    echo '<input id="output" value="">';
?>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/23jzk61m/

Answer (score 1):

Use attributes to store the prices and display the prices on select change selecting the attribute and appending it to the price div

Try something like this:

```
    <?php
    // my connection here
    ?>
    <?php
        $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM products");
        echo '<select class="product">';
            while($obj = $query->fetch_object()){
                echo '
                    <option data-price="'.$obj->price.'" value="'.$obj->product_name.'">'.$obj->product_name.'</option>
            ';
        }
    echo '</select>';
    // if product1 is selected, the price is 100 and show in the textbox
    //
    ?>
    Price:<span class="price"></span>
    <script>
    $(function(){
    $('.product').change(function(){
     var price = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-price');
     $('.price').text(price+'$');
    });
    });
</script>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7h16duh9/

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php // Internet connection here ?>

<select class="ProductName">
    <?
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM products");
  while($obj = $query->fetch_object())
    {?>
    // I assumed '$product_price' as column name. Change it if different
    <option value="<?php echo $obj->product_price; ?>"><?php echo $obj->product_name; ?></option>
    <?php }?>
</select>


<span class="ShowPrice">
    <input type="text" value="">
</span>

<script>
    $('.ProductName').change(function(){
        var Price=$('.ProductName').val();
        $.ajax({url:"Ajax-ShowPrice.php?Price="+Price,cache:false,success:function(result){
            $('.ShowPrice').html(result);
        }});
    }); 
</script>
```

**Ajax-ShowPrice.php** (Create new page. Make sure, if you want to change page name here, change in `<script></script>` tag too. Both are related.)

```
<?
$Price=$_GET['Price'];
?>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $Price;?>">
```

Comment: why go to such length with ajax and another server request?

Comment: I feel easy in this way only. I liked your answer. I will implement your code somewhere @madalinivascu